# PDO execute breaking?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `location_id`, `name`, `location_type`, `parent_id` FROM `location` WHERE `name` LIKE '%?%' AND `location_type` = 2;");
    $query = $dbh->execute(array($location));
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So the problem I'm having is that I cannot seem to get this query to work. I'm using the exact same format for queries throughout the rest of my code and that works perfectly fine.

If I add a debug message, I cannot get past the second line. I have even tried doing a SELECT query without any parameters and I cannot get  it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have 2 things that should be prepared and 2 things which should be in the array to be executed.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Okay so I've changed it so that it's `location_type` = ?; and added the value into the array but I still can't get it to work, even if I just remove that part completely.

Comment: Update your question with the new code and read the duplicate link.